# Receive multiple JSONObject in one AsyncHttpClient request

Tags: php, android

I have a problem in my code. I just want to receive JSONObject from my server. here is a part of my php code after make the request

```
$obj = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS); 
            foreach ($obj as $row) { 
                $trouver = FALSE;
                if (stristr($row->type_of_event, $chaine_rechercher) !== FALSE) $trouver = TRUE;
                else if (stristr($row->name_of_event, $chaine_rechercher) !== FALSE) $trouver = TRUE;
                else if (stristr($row->description_of_event, $chaine_rechercher) !== FALSE) $trouver = TRUE;
                if ($trouver == TRUE){

                        $reponse["id"] = $row->id;
                        $reponse["type_of_event"] = utf8_encode($row->type_of_event);
                        $reponse["description_of_event"] = utf8_encode($row->description_of_event);
                        echo(json_encode($reponse));

                }
            }
```

But the problem is that in my onSuccess in Android code, just first JSONObject is received. here is a part of my android code

```
client.get("my_url", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject json_data) {
                try {

                        int id = json_data.getInt("id");
                        String type = json_data.getString("type_of_event");
                        String description = json_data.getString("description_of_event");
                        id_list.add(id);
                        type_list.add(type);
                        description_list.add(description);

                    ((SearchResultAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Echec de connexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Can you help me ? Please.

Comment: Hows your whole response looking ? Can you post

Comment: Sorry for the silence. here is the response on the web browse.          [{"id":"2","type":"bar","description":"Blue"}]
[{"id":"1","type":"shop","description":"Red"}]
[{"id":"4","type":"Market","description":"Yellow"}] but just the first come on my android . i notice that i am using AsyncHttpClient

Comment: Combine your all data in one json array.

Comment: this is a search i do in a big database so i dont get all data in same time. a seconde json can come 8 seconds after the first. so i want to send each response found during search like any search motor do. example in facebook when you make a search

Comment: Check my ans let me know if it still causes problem

Comment: I don't know how to combine all data in one json Array.  can you help?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: i said that i don't know how to do it. how to combine all data in one json array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try {
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json_data);

      for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
      int id = jsonobj .getInt("id");
      String type = jsonobj .getString("type_of_event");
      String description = jsonobj .getString("description_of_event");
      id_list.add(id);
      type_list.add(type);
      description_list.add(description);
     }
     ((SearchResultAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
} catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it seems that onSuccess method stop receiving after first json received

Comment: @Régis Sehou May be your php code has issue I dont know about it

Comment: i posted it in my question